# Date time save in database

Tags: 8, datetime

I have two very basic vanilla installation of Drupal 8. One I have installed a few months back, and one I installed today.

I have an identical datetime range field in both of them. But I noticed that the older installation (8.8.4) saves the datetime after converting it to UTC format. However, the new installation (8.9.2) saves the date time as is entered in the form.

Is there a configuration or something which is controlling this? This is creating problem using the "Date all day" module I guess.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: The storage time zone didn't change between 8.8.4 and 8.9.2. What changed is probably the local time zone of the new installation. See /admin/config/regional/settings

Comment: It is the same in both cases I can see. The default timezone is specified as UTC. But one is saving in UTC converted form and another in as entered form.
Please find the attached screenshot of the page.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear to you in the local time zone settings.